# Wireless WLAN Transmitter for Desktop Computer?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, desktop-computer

I would like to know whether I can buy a Wireless WLAN Transmitter for my desktop computer in order to not use a internet cable to connect to the internet but rather via my router's wireless WLAN option, or not.

I was thinking about buying the product below:
http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B007K871ES/ref=oh_details_o00_s00_i01?ie=UTF8&psc=1

The idea is to just put this stick in and connect it with my computer and just make it connect to the internet with only this device and not the cable.

I personally think that it actually might not work due to the fact that there is no WLAN card or whatever those devices are called, built-in in my computer but maybe it is possible. That is why I thought I'd just ask the pros.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I generally recommend keeping stationary devices on wired connections, leaving more wireless bandwidth for portable/mobile devices. Also, if you happened to be on gigabit Ethernet before, going from that to that old flavor of Wi-Fi is probably going to disappoint you.

Comment: I actually have a Macbook Pro (Late 2011) 15'', a HP laptop and a desktop PC. From these devices, I only use my Macbook Pro with an external monitor. I only expect the other devices to be 'there' for when I might need to use them :) Therefore, the internet on those devices aren't really that important. I use an ethernet cable on my Macbook Pro, since that is the device I primarily use :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine.  When you insert it into your computer, the device will become your wlan card and connect to your wifi at your house :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The device is going to arrive tomorrow. I am really excited already :o I want to reduce all of my cables at home. That is why I am trying to convert everything that works with cables into wireless connections :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what you've bought is itself a wireless USB network card, so it will work without much hassle. Depending on the internal electronics of the card, it could work just by plugging into a USB port and waiting a few seconds for the Windows driver autoinstall, but if Windows can't find the drivers yo will need to install them manually, ususally using a CD included in the box of the WiFi card.

Now, if you can avoid WiFi as possible and stick to cable, this will give you a better performance, but if you will use your PC only to surf the WEB or to stream low bitrate video (As the one on Youtube) you will not see any performance penalties, unless your local WiFi medium is very populated from neighbours WiFi, I think you should consider this.

Comment: I actually have a Macbook Pro (Late 2011) 15'', a HP laptop and a desktop PC. From these devices, I only use my Macbook Pro with an external monitor. I only expect the other devices to be 'there' for when I might need to use them :) Therefore, the internet on those devices aren't really that important. I use an ethernet cable on my Macbook Pro, since that is the device I primarily use :)